# Get clients browser language in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on multilingual web application which will show the page according to the browser language..I am using GWT in java. How can I get the browser language

Answer (score 0):

GWT itself has support for internationalization (i18n).
You can read about it in their docs [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html).

Comment: I can't really see how I get the browser language :(